# CodeIgniter : controller within a folder, both with the same name

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

[image: imagen]

im having trouble figuring out how to be able to access the methods inside controllers that are inside a subfolder.

I want to access the employee.php methods and find a way to make the server diferentiate between employee/login (as a method of employee/employee.php) and employee/group/add (as a method of employee/group.php).

I've tried configuring routing but it only seems to work with methods, also tried redirections in .htaccess with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I think it is best a best practice in this case name the folder in a different manier respect that of internal file

Answer (score 1):

You're in danger zone here but it should work if you use the complete path :

Use :

```
employee/employee/login
```

just like you do for :

```
employee/group/add
```

That said it is a really bad idea, why would you want to create endless problems ? Change the name of the folder in employeeS for example.

Comment: Just wanted to have a clean way to prepresent methods and entities in a diagram for this api. I'ill use employee/user.php instead of employee/employee.php . Thnx for the input both of you.